# Spyder crashes with error: "It seems the kernel died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart kernel' to continue using this console"

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I have a 64 bit Windows 7 machine I am using Spyder 2.3.8 with Python 2.7 and Matplotlib 1.4.2 ( I tried Matplotlib 1.5.1 and got the same error)

Every time I import matplotlib and then try to plot with it, a window will pop up and has a few times displayed the figure.. but more often than not  I get the restart kernel error.

The code is super simple:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

x_values = [0, 4, 7, 20, 22, 25]
y_values = [0, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
pyplot.plot(x_values, y_values, "o-")

pyplot.ylabel("Value")
pyplot.xlabel("Time")
pyplot.title("Test plot")

pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by updating matplotlib. In my case it was solved by doing this.
To update matplotlib just type `conda update matplotlib` on your terminal.
Hope it will work!